# Editor Configuration file for Visual Studios

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any editor configuration file for visual studios? Currently everyone in my team is using different styles(tabs, spaces) and it is pain while checking-in the code. So is there anything like we have **.vimrc** for visual studios , which can be shared across the team, so that everyone can follow a same style, avoiding pain in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, export the settings you want to share to a *.vssettings* file (**Tools** -> **Import and Export Settings**), and make it available on a network location. Don't export settings that are a matter of taste, such as fonts and colors.

Then, use this file on every computer :

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Options**
2. In **Environment**, select **Import and Export Settings**.
3. Check **Use team settings file**, and specify the location of the *.vssettings* file